# How can I see Hidden HTML Source in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, css

How can I access hidden HTML Source using C#?

The HTML source of the hidden content is shown below.

```
<div id="ll-content-container">Hidden Content</div>
```

The problem is that when I access it using the inspect element (f12 key) in google chrome everything is visible but when I try to access it using view source everything will be hidden.

Thanks

Comment: Could be that the extra content is added through javascript which explains why it is not visible in the initial source. U'd have to emulate/run the javascript to get the generated source

Comment: This normally happens with dynamic data meaning this doesn't exist in the source code, this is added/created once the page has been loaded or when a function has been fired.

Comment: Inspect Element will show to you the current content of the page. View Source will show you the source page, what the browser has received from the server. before running any client-side scripts.

Comment: Really not clear what the issue is. What tells you it is hidden in `view source`? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: To summarize what others already said: it's not hidden, it simply doesn't exist in the source.

Comment: Sorry for maybe not making myself very clear. What I meant was that this website is generating code using javascript and I would like to know if there is a possibility to view that particular source? Thanks for the comments

Comment: Can open any javascript file and read that. If you have more specific issue with how to interact with the new html you need to provide far more details